# How to perform Cross-Validation for glasso to select lambda in R

Tags: cross-validation, graphical-model

I am using glasso for variable selection. To get the best possible value of lambda cross validation is recommended. However, I am not able to find how to perform cross validation for glasso in R. Methods for lasso are variable that require both dependent and independent variables. However, I have only a set of large variable and I am using glasso to build a sparse network of the variables to observe conditional dependencies.

I found on google search a package called cv.glasso. however, I found that it was only description and not the actual package. One package that I found somewhere else is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is an `R` function of CV for `glasso` [here](https://github.com/czarrar/causality_primer/blob/master/journal/2014-07-12_cross_validation_graphical_lasso.Rmd).

Answer (score 1):

There is some [python code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.GraphLassoCV.html#sklearn.covariance.GraphLassoCV) which does this well in my experience. You might be able to call this directly or rewrite it in R.